# .NET Membership - questions

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, coding-style

I would like to ask something regarding membership in .NET. I am getting some problems when I try to use membership. I followed the rules as per given by microsoft site. Just done some settings in Web.config as follows

```
<membership>
   <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
        connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="3"
        requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3"  requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
        enablePasswordReset="true"
        minRequiredPasswordLength="7"   applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Then I have used `CreateUser` method of membership. All the parameters to call the method are fine but sometimes it returns status as `InvalidPassword`. I do not know why it is returning the status but sometimes it is creating user successfully. Can somebody please explain me where I am wrong? This is function I am using:

```
     MembershipUser newUser = Membership.CreateUser(ObjModel.FirstName, ObjModel.password,      ObjModel.Email, null, null, true, out status);
            //ObjModel.FirstName + ObjModel.LastName, ObjModel.LastName, ObjModel.password,ObjModel.Email ,null, null, true, out status);
            Message = status.ToString();
            if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                MembershipUserId = new Guid(Membership.GetUser(ObjModel.FirstName).ProviderUserKey.ToString());
                Roles.AddUserToRole(ObjModel.FirstName + ObjModel.LastName, "Client");
            }
```

Lastly one more question: after I receive success message I want to add this user to role and role would be client. How should I use it? I have not created Roles. when should one create roles? we can create roles independently of the other tables? and what If I have to create one more membership user and but it's role should be admin and so on?Actually what should be the proper flow of creating users, creating roles and adding user roles programmatically? what is application Id in the sql membership tables? Please clear all my doubts . I have searched and tried googling but yet there are some points that are not getting cleared. Please help ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Invalid Password error status/error only comes when the password entered by you does not meet the requirements given in web.config file as explained in above answer.You have to check the password entered by you should contains minimum 3 NonalphanumericCharacters like(@, %, #) and all in combine password should contain 7 digits/numbers/alphabets or whatever.

2) and the flow you are asking. according to me it should work like this . First call CreateUsermethod and after it returns status= success then add that user a role. roles should be created already  and i think yes it is independent of the other membership tables.

3)Similarly you just need to use AddUserTorole method of membership and pass Rolename as one of it's parameter plus User name as first parameter to add role to the  user.

Last but not least 
Stack Over flow can correct me please if I am wrong somewhere because I responsing according to my knowledge and searching from internet

Answer (score 0):

Your invalidpassword error is likely being caused because the password doesn't meet the min password complexity.  try setting the minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters attribute when you declare the membership provider in your web config. (set it to 0 for least complexity).  There may be more settings but can't think of any off the top of my head.

To Manage your roles use the AspNetSqlRoleProvider : declare it in your web config under `<system.web>` like :

`<roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"    connectionStringName="DBCon" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>`

Sorry - no matter what i do the above loses its lf.

Then just update your roles using Roles.CreateRole, Roles.DeleteRole(), Roles.AddUserToRole, Roles.RemoveUserFromRole.

Usually create your roles first - but it doesn't really matter i guess.

The applciation id is exactly like it sounds - a unique reference for your application in this database - you could have more than one application running against your database.

Hope this helps -

Marc